# Django - CheckboxSelectMultiple() with scrollbar

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I will have more than a hundred checkboxes on the form. This looks ugly right now. I am trying to make the checkboxes be in a frame(?) with a vertical scrollbar. Using `height:100px;` in crispy forms doesn't have any affect at all. Using that same in `attr`to `CheckboxSelectMultiple()` or `ModelMultipleChoiceField` throws `unexpected argument attr` error.

Form field:

```
specialities = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField( queryset=spQry ,widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),  label=_('Speciality'), required=True)
```

cripsy form part:

```
 self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('practice_date'),
            Field('gender'),
            Field('specialities', style='max-height:20px!important'),
            StrictButton("Submit", name="submit", value="Submit", type='submit' ,css_class='btn btn-action-success')
        )
```

Is there anyway to have that scrollbar?

Thank you

Comment: can you add `style='overflow-y: scroll;'` to your html element

Answer (score 0):

update your cripsy form part:

```
self.helper = FormHelper()
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('practice_date'),
    Field('gender'),
    Field(Div('specialities', css_class="scrollbar-y")),
    StrictButton("Submit", name="submit", value="Submit", type='submit' ,css_class='btn btn-action-success')

)
```

and add this code to your stylesheet

```css
.scrollbar-y{
   overflow-y: scroll !important;
   max-height:20px !important;
}
```

Comment: It didn't have any effect on the form.

Comment: remove the crispy part and tell the answer

Comment: Still not working. That part is actually applying that `class` to individual checkboxes instead of the group of them. I checked this in developer tool

Comment: **Updated** the answer

Comment: please check and let me know

Comment: Didn't work. Now the class doesn't even appear anywhere  in the developer tool

Comment: please check again